# Need hint for solving the following problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, binomial-coefficients

> If $f(x^{500}-1)=5x^{1015}+3x^{244}+7x+10$. Find the sum of coefficients of $f(x^5+1)$.

Let $x^{500}-1=y$, then $f(y)=5(y+1)^\frac{1015}{500}+3(y+1)^\frac{244}{500}+7(y+1)^\frac{1}{500}+10$.

But, I don't think that it is a right approach as each term of $f(y)$ gets transformed into an infinite series via binomial expansion, in that  case it is not possible to sum the coefficients.

> Another approach(This may be wrong!!,Please check)

Let,$x^{500}-1=x^5+1\implies x^{500}-x^5-1=1$.So,$f(x^5+1)=5(x^{500}-x^5-1)x^{1015}+3(x^{500}-x^5-1)x^{244}+7(x^{500}-x^5-1)x+10(x^{500}-x^5-1)$

> So,the sum of coeffecients$=5-5-5+3-3-3+7-7-7+10-10-10=-25$

Please give  some hints.

Comment: Why did u take $x^{500}-1=x^5+1$?

Comment: @ a m i t y a s:beacuse then $f(x^{500}-1)=f(x^5+1)$ and then $f(x^5+1)$ can be determined explicitly

Comment: Why do they have to be equal? How can u assume this?

Comment: @amityas:i  answered this already in my above comment.Now, please you tell why i can't assume this?

Comment: @PKStyles: no, you told us why you wanted to assume this, you didn't tell us why you could. $x^{500}-1=x^5+1$ only holds for particular values of $x$, not for all $x$ in general.

Comment: @robjohn:beacuse if $x^{500}-1=x^5+1$ then $f(x^{500}−1)=f(x^5+1)$ and then f(x^5+1) can be determined explicitly

Comment: @PKStyles: again, you are telling us why you want to do this, not why it can be done. The coefficients you want are the coefficients of $f(x^5+1)$ for general $x$, not a particular $x$.

Comment: @robjohn:you want to say that i'v  calculated the coffecints of $f$ at the roots of equation $x^{500}-1=x^5+1$?Am i getting you correct?

Comment: If f(x)= f(y) it does NOT necessarily follow that x= y.  Just because you **want** to say "$f(x^{100}- 1)= f(x^5+ 1)$, you cannot assume $x^{500}- 1= x^5+ 1$

Comment: @PKStyles: No. You want to write out the polynomial/series for $g(x)=f(x^5+1)$ and sum the coefficients of $x$ in $g(x)$. This amounts to evaluating $g(1)=f(2)$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The sum of the coefficients of $x$ in $g(x)=f\!\left(x^5+1\right)$ is $g(1)=f(2)$. However, given the formula for $f\!\left(x^{500}-1\right)$, we plug in $x=3^{1/500}$ to get
$$
f(2)=45\cdot3^{3/100}+3\cdot3^{61/125}+7\cdot3^{1/500}+10=68.651334833\dots
$$

Answer (score 0):

I think a good hint is to take a look at factor theorem!

Comment: :I already tried it $x^5+1$ is not even an explicit factor of $x^{500}-1$

Comment: $x^{500}-1=\left(x^5+1\right)\left(x^{495}-x^{490}+x^{485}-\cdots+x^5-1\right)$

Comment: @robjohn:you're right,i commited a silly mistake.I miscalculated $x^{125}$ as $(x^5)^3$